# Why is '1' being added onto my command when I try to run it in PHP

Tags: python, php

I have a python file that calls an api and gets some information back that I then need to use in a PHP file. But running the php gives me back "'1' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." Is this related to me using sys.argv in the python file?
Specifically:

```
id_num = sys.argv[1]
```

My php I am testing looks like this:

```
<?php
function getData($var_one)
{
    $cd_command = 'cd Location';
    $command = 'python getData.py ' . $var_one;
    print($command);
    $output = shell_exec($cd_command && $command);
    return $output;
}

$test_string = getData("CRT67547");
print($test_string);
?>
```

The print is there to make sure nothing was wrong in the command and that print output looked fine.
Print output looked like `python getData.py CRT67547`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*EDIT: reread the question, modified for clarity*

You may want to modify the `shell_exec` parameter in your PHP. `&&` is an `AND` logical operator in PHP, but I assume you want it to be executed in your shell along with your two commands like so:

```
$output = shell_exec($cd_command . '&&' . $command);
```

Or, to make your overall code more concise:

```
function getData($var_one)
{
    $command = 'cd Location && python getData.py ' . $var_one;
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    return $output;
}
```

Your shell should then run `cd Location && python getData.py CRT67547`.

Depending on how you set your Location, you could even do:

```
function getData($var_one)
{
    $command = 'python Location/getData.py ' . $var_one;
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    return $output;
}
```

which you can simplify down to:

```
function getData($var_one)
{
    return shell_exec('python Location/getData.py ' . $var_one);
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Must have been the && that was causing the issue. I got rid of it and used you simplified example.

Comment: Fantastic! I'm glad it worked. Oftentimes our code is 99% right, and all it takes is a little syntax cleanup!